# Does this interface already exist in the standard .NET libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I found myself needing a simple generic interface, and I wrote it, but it turned out to be pretty much the world's simplest interface. I was wondering if it already exists by some other name. I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing something that is already included with the .NET framework.

```
interface IReceiver<T>
{
   void Receive(T obj);
}
```

I can't really find a good list of "standard" interfaces that came with .NET. Does the structure of this interface look familiar to anyone? Have I reinvented something that is already standard?

EDIT: I have a data object and a number of objects interested in receiving the data. Objects interested in receiving the data implement the interface, so that 'routing' lists and maps can send the data to them. The idea is full generalization in the routing, the routing will be data-driven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it sounds like the `Action<T>` delegate type... I don't know of any *interface* equivalent off-hand, but could you just use the delegate instead?

EDIT: Okay, if you need to make the various classes actually implement it, then I'd just leave it as a new interface... especially if you can give it a slightly more meaningful name and description than `IReceiver`.

Comment: It needs to be an interface, because I have lots of classes that need to implement the interface in order to receive the data.

Comment: How would a class implementing an interface resemble the Action delegate?

Comment: @VoidStar: Right, that's unfortunate.

Comment: @Magnus: In cases where you're passing something to another method, often both an interface and a delegate make sense - for example, take `List<T>.Sort` which has overloads taking `IComparer<T>` and `Comparison<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now confident that this isn't some common thing everyone knows about but me.