# Is there a standard Java Receiver/Handler interface?

Tags: java

I have repeatedly find myself wanting to use an interface that looks like this:

```
interface Handler<T> {
  void handle(T toHandle);
}
```

It's particularly useful in situations where you want to enforce a try-finally structure around a resource, without relying on the API user to do this.

Your API implementation can then look like:

```
 public void loadResource(Handler<SomeResource> resourceHandler) {
    SomeResource r = fetchTheResource();
    try {
      resourceHandler(r);
    finally {
      r.close();
    }
 }
```

...and the API consumer can safely do:

```
loader.loadResource(new Handler<SomeResource>() {
  public void handle(SomeResource resource) {
    // use the resource, no need to worry about closing it.
  }
});
```

I'm aware of the `Closeable` interface. That's not quite so general purpose - it can't *force* the consumer to close the resource correctly.

The interface might equally be called `Receiver`. Guava has [`Supplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) which is pretty much the opposite, but no `Receiver`.

Is there some core interface that has this structure that I have missed? Am I somehow doing something that everyone else considers overkill?

I note the exact same question has been asked in a C# context: [Does this interface already exist in the standard .NET libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168531/does-this-interface-already-exist-in-the-standard-net-libraries)

Comment: Don't know if I got the right idea from your question, but are you thinking about something like the Visitor Pattern? See for example [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-visitor)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html !?!

Comment: The visitor pattern is just that - a pattern. What I want is a actual interface matching the signature above.

Comment: Yup, so it looks like Java 8's Consumer fits the bill. Unfortunately I cannot make use of Java 8 just yet. (I appreciate I didn't specify in the question)

Comment: It sounds a bit like [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [`Observer.update(Observable, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html#update%28java.util.Observable,%20java.lang.Object%29), which sadly aren't generic.

Comment: @TimGage: If you can't use Java 8, I would have implemented my own interface `my.package.Consumer<T>` with the method `void accept(T t)`. If you eventually migrate to Java 8, you could adapt your interface to inherit from `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` and automatically extend your old classes to fit into the Java 8 API.

Comment: @jarnbjo: That's pretty much what I have done. It just felt like it should exist in the core - and it does! Just out of reach for now...

Comment: Java really needs C++ RAII

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 has the interface `java.util.function.Consumer<T>`.

If you can't make use of Java 8, but you have Guava, it's kind of like a `com.google.common.base.Function<T, Void>`. Yes, I know this looks a bit smelly, but it does resemble what you want.

Comment: Just to clarify, since I find the naming (Consumer) a little bit confusing. The purpose of this interface is exactly what it's asked for here: "Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result."

Comment: Yes, it looks like Consumer fits the bill. I can't currently use Java 8, but this can go on the list of reasons to sort out the upgrade.